# Как написать bat для перезапуск приложения?

Tags: bat

Подскажите скрипт для bat файла, на перезапуск приложения

Должен проверить приложение **sync.exe**, если работает, то завершает его и запускает по новой, если не работает *(процесс вовсе отсутствует)*, то просто запускает.

Comment: Как узнать что процесс не отвечает?

Comment: Вот вопрос, можно такую проверку выполнить? Если нет, то просто перезапуск

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: поправил вопрос

Comment: Что за sync.exe?

Comment: @eri, а какая разница?

Comment: приложения без окон не могут "не отвечает"

Comment: @eri, так он же удалил эту часть вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
taskkill /im sync.exe & timeout 1 & start "" "sync.exe"
```

Но может потребоваться флаг принудительного завершения:

```
taskkill /f /im sync.exe & timeout 1 & start "" "sync.exe"
```

PS: На запущенность не проверяю потому что одинарный амперсанд игнорирует ошибку.

PPS: `timeout 2` можно заменить на `ping -n 2 127.0.0.1` (с единицей не работает).

Comment: Спасибо!
Завершать завершает, но после таймаута не стартует, выдает ошибку "Не удается найти "sync.exe" Проверьте, правильно ли указано имя и повторите попытку"

Comment: @Evgen, полный путь прописывай к запускаемому файлу.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример на основе калькулятора (WIN10) управление потоком исполнения происходит спомощью конструкции `if-else` а так же комманды `goto` с указанием метки для перехода (что-то типа аналога функций) каждая комманда которая предваряется `@` не будет выводиться на экран

В данном случае название процесса и программы для запуска немного отличаются, поэтому пришлось захардкодить `calc.exe` в `start_app`.
А в первой строке `set app=Calculator.exe`  я задал имя процесса.

Если в `%ERRORLEVEL%` будет не `0` то значит произошла ошибка и процесс не был найден среди запущенных.

```
set app=Calculator.exe

@tasklist /fi "ImageName eq %app%" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "%app%">NUL
@if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (goto restart_app) else (goto start_app)

:restart_app
@taskkill /f /im "%app%"
@timeout /t 1 /nobreak
@goto start_app

:start_app 
@start "" "calc.exe"
@goto exit

:exit
```

Еще можно сделать универсальный скрипт, при условии что имена процесса и программы будут совпадать:

```
@tasklist /fi "ImageName eq %1" /fo csv 2>NUL | find /I "%1">NUL
@if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (goto restart_app) else (goto start_app)

:restart_app
@taskkill /f /im "%1"
@timeout /t 1 /nobreak
@goto start_app

:start_app 
@start "" "%1"
@goto exit

:exit
```

Использовать его очень просто, можно дать подходящее имя скрипту (restarter.bat) и поместить в папку `System32` или любой путь где система найдет. При запуске вторым параметром указываем программу например:  `restarter notepad.exe`

Comment: `@goto start_app` - вроде это лишнее. А помещать свои скрипты в system32 - это какая-то жесть.

Comment: а закидывать туда либы не жесть? к тому же я написал **или любой путь где система найдет**).    `@goto start_app` лишнее, но я просто решил показать одновременно как можно организовывать переходы